# How execute Powershell script in PHP and output result?

Tags: php, powershell

Studying the interaction of Php with Powershell
Try the simplest script:

```
<?php
$query = shell_exec("powershell.exe -File E:\test.ps1");
echo $query; 
?>
```

In the script test.ps1 - for example "Test-Connection Server"

Need to the answer in Powershell returned to the page Php, but in response to a white paper...
Please tell me some solution for this problem.. do Not have shell_exec. There may be other options?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the output of powershell script in a variable and then echo it. Just change `$psDIR` to your PowerShell path (e.g. `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v2.0\`)

```
<?php
$psPath = "powershell.exe";
$psDIR = "PathToPowrshell";
$psScript = "E:\test.ps1";
$runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
$runCMD = $psPath." ".$runScript;
$output= shell_exec($runCMD);
echo( '<pre>' );
echo( $output );
echo( '</pre>' );
?>
```

Comment: `$runCMD` isn't defined and `$psPath` is never used?

Comment: Good spot forgot to definy it

Comment: Ahh, now it makes sense :-D

Comment: <?php
$psPath = "powershell.exe";
$psDIR = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\";
$psScript = "E:\test2.ps1";
$runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
$runCMD = $psPath." ".$runScript;
$output= shell_exec($runCMD);
echo( '<pre>' );
echo( $output );
echo( '</pre>' );
?>

Comment: Do you get any errors? also make sure all your paths are correct.